# RegEx: How do I capture the dollar amount?

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the dollar amount from each of these lines:

```
On December 31, 2018, I had $1 thousand.

I had $5 million on December 31, 2018.

The amount of money available was $5,000,000 based on the information provided.

The family, on December 31, 2018, held approximately $3 billion in cash.
```

I have tried using

```
(\$\d+.\w+)
```

but it only captures the $1 thousand, $3 million, $5,000 or $3 billion. The entire dollar amount from option 2 isn't captured.

Comment: /\$\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?/gm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `(\$\d+( \w+|[\d,]+))`?

https://regex101.com/r/LlnUPj/1

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(\$\d+.\w+)` does not fully match `$5,000,000` as the dot (that can match any character, so also a comma) only matches once in the pattern and `\w` and `\d` do not match a comma.

Note that `\w+` matches 1+ word characters and can for example also match `$5 test`

---

For a match only, you don't need a capture group. You could make the pattern a bit more specific and extend it accordingly:

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion))?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\$` Match `$`
- `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` match 1-3 digits and optionally repeat `,` and 3 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:thousand|[mb]illion)` Match either thousand, million or billion
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q9LcNQ/1).